# What is the longest trampoline?

Tags: code-golf, sequence, array

In this challenge we are going to consider lists of integers such that for every member \$x\$ at index \$i\$ then the indexes \$i+x\$ and \$i-x\$ have the value \$x+1\$ or are out of bounds for the list.  We will call these trampoline lists.

If we play around with these for a while we can notice that if we start a list with a certain value there is a limit on how long the list can be.  For example let's start with `3` at the first value.

```
[3,...
```

Now we want to make this as long as possible.  If we make it 4 long or longer we know the 4th value has to be `4`.

```
[3,?,?,4,...
```

That tells us that the 8th value (if it exists) has to be `5`

```
[3,?,?,4,?,?,?,5,...
```

That tells us the value at 3 is `6`

```
[3,?,6,4,?,?,?,5,...
```

Which tells us the value at 9 is `7`

```
[3,?,6,4,?,?,?,5,7,...
```

Which tells us the value at 2 is `8`

```
[3,8,6,4,?,?,?,5,7,...
```

Which tells us the value at 10 is `9`

```
[3,8,6,4,?,?,?,5,7,9...
```

Which tells us the value at 1 is `10`.  But we already filled in that as `3`.  So there can't be a 10th value otherwise things break down.  The longest it can ever be is 9.  That tells us that the maximal trampoline list starting with 3 looks like:

```
[3,8,6,4,?,?,?,5,7]
```

Where the `?`s can take on multiple values.

## Task

Given a postive integer \$n\$ as input output a maximal valid trampoline list starting with \$n\$.

This is a [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenge, see the tag wiki for a description on defaults for IO.  This challenge follows the defaults there.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize the size of your program's source code as measured in bytes.

## Test cases

In the first column we have the input. In the second we have a template with `?`s where there are multiple possible correct outputs.  In the last we have an example of a correct output for the given input.

```
1 [1,2,?] [1,2,1]
2 [2,5,3,?,?,4] [2,5,3,4,2,4]
3 [3,8,6,4,?,?,?,5,7] [3,8,6,4,6,6,3,5,7]
4 [4,11,9,7,5,?,?,?,?,6,8,10] [4,11,9,7,5,7,7,8,4,6,8,10]
5 [5,14,12,10,8,6,?,?,?,?,?,7,9,11,13] [5,14,12,10,8,6,9,9,10,11,5,7,9,11,13]
```

If your answer matches the template *and* is a valid trampoline list it is correct.  You should not output the template itself.

Comment: To clarify: once you have the template, can you just fill in the ? with numbers large enough to exceed the bounds of the existing list?

Comment: @Jonah That works.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>15</s>  14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
×3Ṗ+×ɗRṚ;$m2;@
```

A monadic Link that accepts a positive integer and yields a longest trampoline as a list of positive integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//w5cz4bmWK8OXyZdS4bmaOyRtMjtA////NQ)**

#### How?

Trampolines are \$3n\$ long, start with \$n\$ and are then filled at the leftmost then rightmost available slots starting at \$3n-1\$ descending until \$n\$ slots are left, which need filling with numbers that will go out of bounds in both directions.

i.e. the template is:

```
[n, 3n-1, 3n-3, ..., <n ?'s>, ..., 3n-4, 3n-2]
```

The code starts with a list from \$1\$ to \$3n-1\$ and adds \$3ni\$ to the entries at indices \$i\leq n\$ (the ones that will end up at the `?`s in the template). It then prefixes this with its reverse, appends the forward version, discards every other element, and prefixes with \$n\$ to give a trampoline.

```
×3Ṗ+×ɗRṚ;$m2;@ - Link: integer, n       e.g. 3
×3             - multiply (n) by three       9
      R        - range (n)                   [1,2,3]
     ɗ         - last three links as a dyad:
  Ṗ            -   pop (3n)                  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    ×          -   (3n) multiply (range n)   [9,18,27]
   +           -   add                       [10,20,30,4,5,6,7,8]
         $     - last two links as a monad:
       Ṛ       -   reverse                   [8,7,6,5,4,30,20,10]
        ;      -   concatenate               [8,7,6,5,4,30,20,10,10,20,30,4,5,6,7,8]
           2   -   two
          m    -   modulo slice              [8,  6,  4,   20,   10,   30,  5,  7]
             @ - with swapped arguments:
            ;  -   (n) concatenate           [3,8,6,4,20,10,30,5,7]
```

Comment: @thejonymyster thanks, that first number should be `n`, so it's a three, the five was a typo.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 70 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i=(a=Array(w=n*3).fill(w),0))=>a[i]?f(n+1,i-n,f(n+1,i+=a[i]=n)):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZchBCsIwEAXQvSeZ36bFWt0Io3iO4mKojYyESUnF4ukjghvJ7vEe8pJlTDo/G4u3KWfPZE6ZhC8pyZtWtqpH6zUEWuG2AJ9k0OvZk9Wd08bcTzV/nw04Sh6jLTFMbYh38tQBm//ZFdMXsy/mAOQP)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (            // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,             //   n = input
  i = (          //   i = position, initialized to 0
    a = Array(   //   build an array a[]
      w = n * 3  //   of w = n * 3 entries
    ).fill(w),   //   filled with w
    0            //
  )              //
) =>             //
a[i] ?           // if we're not out of bounds:
  f(             //   do a recursive call:
    n + 1,       //     use n + 1 as the value
    i - n,       //     use i - n as the position
    f(           //     do another recursive call:
      n + 1,     //       use n + 1 as the value
      i +=       //       use i + n as the position
        a[i] = n //       and set a[i] to n
    )            //     end of recursive call
  )              //   end of recursive call
:                // else:
  a              //   return a[]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 100 bytes

```python
def g(a,n,i):
 if len(a)>i>=0:g(a,n+1,i+n);a[i]=n;g(a,n+1,i-n)
def f(n):g(a:=[3*n]*3*n,n,0);print(a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3U1JS0xTSNRJ18nQyNa24FDLTFHJS8zQSNe0y7WwNrMAy2oY6mdp5mtaJ0ZmxtnnWcDHdPE0ukPY0jTxNkEor22hjrbxYLSABNM5A07qgKDOvBGgWxK4daflFCpkKmXkKRYl56akahjpmmlZpGplQaZiTAA)

Uses the same recursive concept as [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253509/113573).

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
4*ŸI·._¦ÂìιнI†
```

Inspired by [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253505/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9vc2FiaWX//zQqxbhJwrcuX8Kmw4LDrM650L1J4oCg//8z) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9vc2FiaWX/NUVOPyIg4oaSICI/TkT/NCrFuE7Cty5fwqbDgsOszrnQvU7igKD/LP8).

**Explanation:**

```python
                #  example input: 3
4*              # Multiply the (implicit) input by 4
                #  STACK: 12
  Ÿ             # Pop and push a list in the range [(implicit) input, 4*input]
                #  STACK: [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
   I·           # Push the input doubled
                #  STACK: [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],6
     ._         # Rotate the list that many times towards the left
                #  STACK: [9,10,11,12,3,4,5,6,7,8]
       ¦        # Remove the first value
                #  STACK: [10,11,12,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        Â       # Bifurcate it; shorter for Duplicate & Reverse copy
                #  STACK: [10,11,12,3,4,5,6,7,8],[8,7,6,5,4,3,12,11,10]
         ì      # Prepend the second list to the first
                #  STACK: [8,7,6,5,4,3,12,11,10,10,11,12,3,4,5,6,7,8]
          ι     # Uninterleave it into two parts
                #  STACK: [[8,6,4,12,10,11,3,5,7],[7,5,3,11,12,10,4,6,8]]
           н    # Pop and only leave the first inner list
                #  STACK: [8,6,4,12,10,11,3,5,7]
            I†  # Filter the input to the front of the list
                #  STACK: [3,8,6,4,12,10,11,5,7]
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔Ｅθ⁺θ⊗ιηＩ⁺⁺⮌⊞Ｏ⊕ηθＥθ×³θ✂η¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUwxDsIwENt5RceLVAaEmDohWDoAEfCBNJxIpDRN7pJ@PyQVg23Zsq2NIr0oV8roQ073PE9IEMWwOzPbr4ebChD7TrrMTa9Lnhx@wAoh@s7UniTrE1wUJ9hKGz1xRWIEmdk8ApJKC8HoNeGMPtW9qetY8b9/2xkZji1rvy9nNYLpu0O1Qymnsl/dDw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔Ｅθ⁺θ⊗ιη
```

Create a range from `n` to `3n-2` in steps of 2.

```
Ｉ⁺⁺⮌⊞Ｏ⊕ηθＥθ×³θ✂η¹
```

Increment that range (giving `n+1`, `n+3`, ... `3n-1`), append `n`, reverse the result (giving `n`, `3n-1`, `3n-3`, ... `n+1`), append `n` copies of `3n`, then append the range excluding the first element. This outputs `n`, `3n-1`, `3n-3`, ... `n+1`, `3n`, ... `3n`, `n+2`, ... `3n-2` as desired.